# PhantomJS not capturing <rect> SVG element on screenshots

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to capture screenshots of various SVG/HTML docs. I'm having an issue where the screenshot isn't capturing the  element of the SVG.

Here's the HTML that has the SVG code that's not working. Note that the text elements of the SVG are showing up. In this doc the  are the elements giving the boxes their blue border, and those are what's not showing up on the screenshot. https://pastebin.com/EdQQdUkD

Here's what I believe to be the offending  code:

```
<rect stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="2" ry="2" rx="2" height="60" width="100" stroke="#077bbe" fill="transparent" id="v-36"></rect>
```

Here's a screenshot of what the SVG looks like when I render in a Chrome, Firefox, or Safari browser on Mac OSX: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBh12.jpg

Here's a screenshot of what PhantomJS is generating upon screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqzRY.jpg

Here's the PhantomJS code I'm using to capture the screenshot:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
url, output, width, height;

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    valid = [200, 201, 301, 302]
    if(response.id == 1 && valid.indexOf(response.status) == -1 ){
        console.log('Received a non-200 OK response, got: ', response.status);
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
}

address = system.args[1];
output = system.args[2];
width = system.args[3];
height = system.args[4];
timeout = system.args[5];

console.log("Args: ", system.args);
console.log("Screenshotting: ", address, ", to: ", output);

page.viewportSize = { width: parseInt(width), height: parseInt(height) };
console.log("Viewport: ", JSON.stringify(page.viewportSize));

page.open(address, function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    // Scroll to bottom of page, so all resources are triggered for downloading
    window.setInterval(function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log('scrolling', window.document.body.scrollTop);
        window.document.body.scrollTop = window.document.body.scrollTop + 1024;
      });
    }, 255);

    // scroll back to top for consistency, right in time (sometimes)
    // logo's dissapear when scrolling down
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      });
    }, timeout - 5);

    // after the timeout, save the screenbuffer to file
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      page.render(output);
      phantom.exit();
    }, timeout);
  }
});
```

I've tried this on PhantomJS versions 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1 and still the same problem.

Comment: Could you add your PhantomJS script, screenshot made from PhantomJS and a screenshot made in a normal browser to the question?

Comment: @Vaviloff Sure! Just updated it.